# Prevent page from reloading when connecting to Mongo db using nodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular

i am here trying to link two page together using "_id" of data saved by passing it in url. but i am having my page to reload when i click on href link in angular which hits to link in nodejs. here is my code 
angularJs

```
 <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="/ordercustomer/{{x._id}}">    {{ x.orders.length ||  0 }} order </a>
```

Node js

```
app.get('/ordercustomer/:id', function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.params.id);

        console.log('I received another get request');
       dbConn.then(function(db) {
       var dd = db.db("customermanagement");
   dd.collection('customers').findOne({_id:ObjectId(req.params.id)},function(err, results) {

     console.log(results);
     res.redirect('/index1.html#!/ordercustomer/'+req.params.id)
      });

    });
});
```

where index.html is my main page in angular routing.
app.js

```
 when('/ordercustomer/:userid1', {

                   templateUrl: 'ordercustomer.html',
               controller: 'ordercustomerCtrl'
              }).
```

Comment: Why you are using href. you can write ng click on a tag and use $http to call the api whatever you have created in node js

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary thank you sir. i have got the solution

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary sir if i submit a form using ng-submit and http service res.redirect takes me nowhere what to do to fix it

Comment: 1st you should not redirect from node server. what you can do is : retrun some json response in get api like : `{ status: 1000 , and your stuff }` than depending on your status you can confirm that api has done it's work. and on based of this response code from client js you can use redirection. let me know if you want me to show you small code for that. will put it in answer

Comment: alright sir send me the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your node get api would be:

```
app.get('/ordercustomer/:id', function(req, res, next){
   dbConn.then(function(db) {
     var dd = db.db("customermanagement");
     dd.collection('customers').findOne({_id:ObjectId(req.params.id)},
      function(err, results) {
       res.status(200).send({ status: 1000 }); //and other json fileds whatever you want to send back to client
     });
   });
 });
```

And in your angular client controller :

```
$scope.yourSubmitFunction = function(id){
   $http({
       url : '/ordercustomer/' + id,
       method: 'GET'
   }).then(function(result){
        //this is your result from node api
        if(result.status === 1000){
           //use $window or $location for redirection to your page
        }
   })
};
```